# Ninject - Xml Configuration module

Tags: c#, xml, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an interface that implements in multiple classes. These classes handle their very specific tasks that are intended to. So I'm trying to get the instance of the class I want through ninject. Those binding needs to be set up in the XML file and load whatever the class instance I need.

**Binding XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<module name="Downloader">
  <bind service="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Runtime.IDotNetActivity, Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories" 
        to="TV.ABC.InvoiceDownloader, TV.ABC" />
  <bind service="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Runtime.IDotNetActivity, Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories"
        to="TV.ABC.PaymentsDownloader, TV.ABC" />
</module>
```

**Code**

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = new NinjectSettings { LoadExtensions = false };
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, new XmlExtensionModule());
            string executionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(string.Format(@"{0}\NinjectModules.xml", executionPath));

            IEnumerable<INinjectModule> modules = GetModules(kernel, xDoc);
            kernel.Load(modules);

            var objtest = kernel.Get<IDotNetActivity>();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<INinjectModule> GetModules(IKernel kernel, XDocument document)
        {
            var elementProcessors = kernel.Components.GetAll<IModuleChildXmlElementProcessor>()
                                          .ToDictionary(processor => processor.XmlNodeName);

            return (from moduleElement in document.Elements("module")
                    select new XmlModule(moduleElement, elementProcessors)).Cast<INinjectModule>();
        }
    }
```

I expect to load all the modules defined in the XML file.

***The output is as follows, throws an error***
Ninject.ActivationException: 'Error activating IDotNetActivity
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
  1) binding from IDotNetActivity to CustomerInvoiceDownloaderActivity
  2) binding from IDotNetActivity to CustomerPaymentsDownloaderActivity
Activation path:
  1) Request for IDotNetActivity

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IDotNetActivity only once.
'

***Can someone helps me why this issue is coming up?***

Comment: Thats expected behaviour. Use `kernel.GetAll()` to retrieve all implementations